# How to access a field of exif data from a Photoshop filter plug-in (Photoshop SDK)

Tags: c++, objective-c, visual-studio, cocoa, photoshop

I'm looking for a very specific piece of information. I could make this a rather detailed question I guess but I'd rather try keeping it short and to the point. 
I need to acces a piece of meta data (exif information) from within a Photoshop filter plug-in. I have never dealt with exif data from within a Photoshop plug-in or without and the PS SDK documentation is of a form that leaves a lot of questions. I would eventually get there but was wondering if anyone here has done this before and could help me out with an example. I'd be very grateful for that...

What we need should be documented here in the SDK:

```
documentation/html/group___resource_suite.html
documentation/html/imageresourcessection.html
```

The latter document says that the resource ID I need to retrieve the exif data is 1059 (decimal) and that accessing Exif data is supported since PS 7.0 which is good. But the SDK has no information (that I found) as to what you get, pointer? pointer to what? They just tell you to look at the exif spec. So do I get a pointer to the RAW binary exif data and if so how to I extract a field from that.

The specifications for the Exif data are here: 
http://exif.org/specifications.html

As an example I'd like to get at this exif field:

```
Tag Name                            Field Name          Dec     Hex     Type  Count
Image title                         ImageDescription    270     10E     ASCII Any
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: After a deeper research I've found the following (an excerpt from the documentation):

Document: Photoshop API Guide.
Argument: Callbacks.

> The callback routines are organized into “suites” collections of
>   related routines which implement a particular functionality.

The suites are described by a pointer to a record containing:

1. a 2 byte version number for the suite,
2. a 2 byte count of the number of routines in the suite,
3. a series of function pointers for the callback routines.

You are interested in the **Property suite**.

Current version: 1; Adobe Photoshop: 5.0; Routines: 2.

Properties are identified by a signature and key, which form a pair to
identify the property of interest.

**Adobe Photoshop’s signature is always '8BIM' (0x3842494D).**

The EXIF property is controlled by The Japan Electronic Industry Development Association (JEIDA) and Electronic Industries Association of Japan (EIAJ) which merged in Novemeber of 2000. The EXIF specification can be downloaded from their web site at the following location.

http://it.jeita.or.jp/jhistory/document/standard/exif_eng/jeida49eng.htm

```
GetPropertyProc( )

MACPASCAL OSErr (*GetPropertyProc) (OSType signature, OSType key, int32 index, int32 * simpleProperty, Handle * complexProperty);
```

This routine allows you to get information about the document currently being processed.

```
property name: propEXIFData 
id:EXIF 
type:complex (modifiable)
description:Camera and device data.
```

To recap I'll write some juicy code:

```
GetPropertyProc getProperty = formatParamBlock->propertyProcs->getPropertyProc;
rc = getProperty(0x3842494D, propEXIFData, 0, &simpProp, &compProp);
if ( rc )   
    return;

GetPIHandleSizeProc getSize = formatParamBlock->handleProcs->getSizeProc;
int32 size = getSize(compProp);
if ( !size ) 
   return;

LockPIHandleProc lock = formatParamBlock->handleProcs->lockProc;
uint8* exif = (uint8 *)lock(compProp, false);
if ( !exif ) 
   return;
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. The question is not about the PiPL however nor is it about 'meta data for a plug-in'. The question is about retreiving meta data from any individual image. I believe to have pointed out the proper files in the documentation above.

Comment: I've read the imageresourcessection.html file, but it only specifies where in the PSD is the EXIT data stored, you shouldn't need that because you're not opening a PSD from the outside. Instead, from the plugin, you should call an API (SDK) function to get the EXIF information, that is you should query a property.

Comment: I'll have to review this later. Since the time for that was ending I awarded you the bounty. Yours was the most involved answer after all.

Answer (score 0):

Here's is a code sample using the [Exiv2](http://www.exiv2.org/doc/index.html) Library: http://www.exiv2.org/doc/exifprint_8cpp-example.html

```
// ***************************************************************** -*- C++ -*-
// exifprint.cpp, $Rev: 2286 $
// Sample program to print the Exif metadata of an image

#include <exiv2/exiv2.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cassert>

int main(int argc, char* const argv[])

try {

if (argc != 2) {
    std::cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " file\n";
    return 1;
}

Exiv2::Image::AutoPtr image = Exiv2::ImageFactory::open(argv[1]);
assert(image.get() != 0);
image->readMetadata();

Exiv2::ExifData &exifData = image->exifData();
if (exifData.empty()) {
    std::string error(argv[1]);
    error += ": No Exif data found in the file";
    throw Exiv2::Error(1, error);
}
Exiv2::ExifData::const_iterator end = exifData.end();
for (Exiv2::ExifData::const_iterator i = exifData.begin(); i != end; ++i) {
    const char* tn = i->typeName();
    std::cout << std::setw(44) << std::setfill(' ') << std::left
              << i->key() << " "
              << "0x" << std::setw(4) << std::setfill('0') << std::right
              << std::hex << i->tag() << " "
              << std::setw(9) << std::setfill(' ') << std::left
              << (tn ? tn : "Unknown") << " "
              << std::dec << std::setw(3)
              << std::setfill(' ') << std::right
              << i->count() << "  "
              << std::dec << i->value()
              << "\n";
}

return 0;
}
//catch (std::exception& e) {

//catch (Exiv2::AnyError& e) {

catch (Exiv2::Error& e) {
    std::cout << "Caught Exiv2 exception '" << e.what() << "'\n";
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Since I said that I have not dealt with Exif information outside of a PS plug-in either... Thank you for posting this. I had found the same library before and it's even available for commercial use. However a simple copy/paste of a vaguely on-topic source code from another web site was not what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

I combined response [vulkanino](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9567749/4596613) and [ThdK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9567595/4596613). My method uses the function PIGetEXIFData declared in file PropertyUtils.h that returns a binary exif. Next, this exif decoded [Exiv2](http://www.exiv2.org/doc/index.html) library

```
#include <PropertyUtils.h>
#include <PIProperties.h>

#include <exif.hpp>

void printExif() {
    Handle handle;
    checkSPErr(PIGetEXIFData(handle));
    std::string ss;
    checkSPErr(HandleToString(handle, ss));

    Exiv2::ExifData exifData;
    Exiv2::ExifParser::decode(exifData, reinterpret_cast<const Exiv2::byte*>(ss.data()), ss.size());
    Exiv2::ExifData::const_iterator end = exifData.end();
    for (Exiv2::ExifData::const_iterator i = exifData.begin(); i != end; ++i) {
        const char* tn = i->typeName();
        std::cout << std::setw(44) << std::setfill(' ') << std::left
            << i->key() << " "
            << "0x" << std::setw(4) << std::setfill('0') << std::right
            << std::hex << i->tag() << " "
            << std::setw(9) << std::setfill(' ') << std::left
            << (tn ? tn : "Unknown") << " "
            << std::dec << std::setw(3)
            << std::setfill(' ') << std::right
            << i->count() << "  "
            << std::dec << i->value()
            << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: It's helpful to explain your answer, rather than just providing some code.